# PHP socket_read does not return empty string ''

Tags: php, sockets

Hi there's problem with the socket_read function below, it does not return empty string '' after it has finished reading the data. On second call to socket_read() it just hang there, the page keep loading in browser with no return.
It works if the server close the connection, is it a must for server to close the client socket ? Thanks

```
    $json = $_GET['json'];

    /* Get the port for the WWW service. */
    // $service_port = getservbyname('www', 'tcp');
    $service_port = "1111";

    /* Get the IP address for the target host. */
    $address = "192.168.3.5";

    /* Create a TCP/IP socket. */
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    if ($socket === false) {
        echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
        die();
    } else {
        //echo "OK.\n";
    }

    //echo "Attempting to connect to '$address' on port '$service_port'...";
    $result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
    if ($result === false) {
        echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
        die();
    } else {
        //echo "OK.\n";
    }

    $out = '';

    //echo "Sending HTTP HEAD request...";
    $result = socket_write($socket, $json, strlen($json));

    if ($result === false) {
        echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
        die();
    } else {
        //echo "OK.\n";
    }



    echo socket_read($socket, 2048);
    echo socket_read($socket, 2048);
//  
     // while (socket_read($socket, 2048) !== '') {
        // echo $out;
//       
     // }
//   
     socket_close($socket);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's exactly what I'd expect it to do - socket_read() will never return an empty string unless you open it a binary and the server responds with '\0'.

You seem to be trying to write an HTTP client. If you are, STOP NOW, throw away your code and go read up on the Curl extension. HTTP is not a simple protocol, and you've still got a lot to learn about how the simple stuff works. You are curently relying on the socket state and the format of the data to determine the data flow - but HTTP uses neither.

If you want to learn how HTTP works, then there's lots of documentation on the internet - the RFC's are a must, but are not a gentle introduction. If your objective is to develop an application, then use curl (or even the HTTP stream wrappers).

Comment: Hi, I did send the '\0' from the server but still it does not return empty string. Alternatively I just send ## from the server then check ## in php to end the loop. 
I am aware of the curl, not trying to write a HTTP client. I just want the php to communicate to the c++ winsock application that I have written. 
Thanks for the help.